# Fetching Record from CRM 2011 using jQuery/javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, .net, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011

I am trying to get data from CRM 2011 through jQuery but I am unable to fetch the data. Here is my code:

```js
function GetConfigurations() {

var oDataPath = Xrm.Page.context.getServerUrl() + "/xrmservices/2011/organizationdata.svc";

    var filter = "/new_plugins_configurationSet?" +

  "$top=1";

var dataUrl=oDataPath + filter;
alert(dataUrl);

try
{
     $.ajax({url: dataUrl, success: function(result){
            alert(result);
        },error:function(error){console.log(error);alert("error");}});
}
catch(err)
{
    alert("error" + err.message);
}



}
```

This gives me the following error in the console of the CRM form:

[image]

Am I doing something wrong in the code?

**Edited :**

I have done changes in Js Code and now I am writing new_plugins_configurationset but it is returning Cross origin error even tough I am calling JS Code from CRM forms.

> Here what I want to achieve is that on opening of one Entity CRM form,
>   I want to read a second entity and put value in control of opening
>   entity. that's why I am calling second entity using JS code.

Comment: Those aren't errors, they're warnings. The second one is because of your use of `async: false` which needs to be removed. I'd suggest you check the network tab of the console after making the request to see what the response code and text is. If the request is failing it should hopefully give you a useful error message you can debug

Comment: hey @RoryMcCrossan I have removed async:false but still it won't able to call some how. is there any mistake in request?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I have one question that should we have to allow CORS in CRM to call organization service from javascript?

Comment: Within CRM form, CORS not at all needed for CRM service calls. Did you debug & see odataUri value?

Comment: @ArunVinoth I have checked the URl and here it is 
http://ServerAddress/OrganizationName/xrmservices/2011/organizationdata.svc/new_plugins_configuration?$select=testFirstName&$top=1

Comment: If you navigate to that URI into Chrome, what happens? You can debug there... Also, v1.5 of [Jason Lattimer's RESTBuilder](https://github.com/jlattimer/CRMRESTBuilder/releases) supports CRM 2011. It's a very helpful tool for building OData queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have resolved my problem. I was doing following mistakes through which I was unable to Get data from CRM.

- The issue was with dataset name, it should end with `Set` keyword.
  For my entity it should be new_plugins_configurationSet.
- I was using `Xrm.Page.context.getServerUrl();` method to get serverUrl but by using this it's returning Cross origin error, so I used
  `Xrm.Page.context.getClientUrl()` to get complete server Url.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is with dataset name, it should end with `Set` keyword. For your entity it should be `new_plugins_configurationSet`.

Comment: I have now write new_plugins_configurationset but now it's givig me cross origion error even tough I am calling CRM through CRM contact form

Comment: Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://server/organizationname/xrmservices/2011/organizationdata.svc/new_plugins_configurationSet?$top=1. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing).
this is the error now I am getting

Comment: what I want to achieve is on opening of one entity form I want field of another entity to be set in a control of opening entity.